# How to remove last subdir from path using tcl?

Tags: tcl

```
c:\root\machine\spec\detail\
z:\test\room\tool\
```

i want to remove the last subdir to become like this :

```
c:\root\machine\spec\
z:\test\room\
```

How to do it using TCL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can try using [`file`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm) if you don't mind the forward slashes instead and the non training slash:

```
% set line "c:\\root\\machine\\spec\\detail\\"
c:\root\machine\spec\detail\
% file dirname $line
c:/root/machine/spec
```

Otherwise, if you want to keep everything as you mentioned it in your question, then I guess a quick [`regsub`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm) should be fine:

```
% set line "c:\\root\\machine\\spec\\detail\\"
c:\root\machine\spec\detail\
% regsub {[^\\]+\\$} $line ""
c:\root\machine\spec\
```

Or a non-re solution; split and join:

```
% set line "c:\\root\\machine\\spec\\detail\\"
c:\root\machine\spec\detail\
% join [lreplace [split $c "\\"] end-1 end-1] "\\"
c:\root\machine\spec\
```

---

The difference would be that `file` will know when the path you are giving it is the highest possible level while the other solutions won't (they return empty string):

```
% set line "c:\\"
c:\
% file dirname $line
c:/
% regsub {[^\\]+\\$} $line ""

% join [lreplace [split $c "\\"] end-1 end-1] "\\"

%
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise to just stick with the `file` subcommands, that is, [`file split`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm#M35) and [`file join`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm#M19) (whatever the purpose of massaging the file paths):

```
% set pathElements [file split $line]
c: root machine spec detail
% set baseDir [file join {*}[file join [lrange $pathElements 0 end-1]]]
c:/root/machine/spec
```

This will make your script more portable (canonical Tcl file paths). If you need to have the OS-native file paths, use [`file nativename`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm#M24) as a last step:

```
% file nativename $baseDir
c:/root/machine/spec
```

(This happens to be the same as the Tcl path on my OS, but on Windows, this will show backslashes as separators.)

Comment: `file dirname` (as Jerry writes) plus `file nativename` will do the same, but the above is more generic (you may decide to strip off several path levels).

Comment: Why is file join repeated twice?